# setting image in the center of a table view cell using constraintsWithVisualFormat

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uitableview, constraint-programming

I am trying to put an image in the center of a table view cell using constraints programmatically.

I have taken an working example from the internet and updated it to this:

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(<=1)-[image(10)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

What am I doing wrong? The image disappears from the table view cell when I set this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your `viewsDict` is set up incorrectly? Try this

```
// Center horizontally
var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:[superview]-(<=1)-[image]",
  options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX,
  metrics: nil,
  views: ["superview":contentView, "image":imageView])

contentView.addConstraints(constraints)
```

The other possible problem is if the `contentView` is not set up with constraints to make it the right size.  Take a look at the `contentView` and see what it's size is.

Comment: Thanks, but tried this out and it's not working. Still missing something out.

Comment: What are the bounds of the contentView object?

Comment: (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 43.5)